# Как подключить привод хоста к Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, виртуализация

Всем привет!
Возникла проблема. Есть виртуальная машина с ОС Ubuntu. Пользуюсь VirtualBox. В носителях подключила привод хоста, разрешила прямой доступ. Диск в ОС появился, но не могу его открыть. При монтировании возникает ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: *что делать?* — для начала изложить в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]), чего вы, собственно, ожидаете от «операционной системы».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я думала это очевидно, что мне надо открыть диск в данной ОС

Comment: насколько я наслышан, в мире ms/windows эфвемизм «открыть диск» используется вместо термина «примонтировать раздел». если вам действительно надо примонтировать раздел, то попробуйте его примонтировать. подсказка: для этого используется программа *mount*.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` чё показывает?

Comment: Ввожу sudo fdisk -l , но диск там просто не отображается

Comment: какая файловая система на диске? и установлена ли соответствующая поддержка в ubuntu? Связанный вопрос: https://askubuntu.com/q/525243/3712